# Create a Parallax effect using scroll as a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

What is the name or how can I make the effect of the scroll (when a scroll happens the page leads the user to another section of the page without showing the scrollbar) of the website below:

[Website](https://kuon.space/#top)

And how it can be do it using pure css/js or React if possible?

Comment: I find those effects seriously annoying. 1.3 Mb of page with maybe 1kb of actual content, surely you can do better? :-)

Comment: the weight it's not because the js tho and you can do pretty things too: https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the they're using a fullpage or fullscreen scrolling effect.

Here is the github link for the package they're using to do it:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate it!